# implementing the closeButton actoin in JXMapKit

Tags: java, swing, maps, swingx

I need to add functionality to the close button in my class that extends the JXMapKit (like saving the location and *EXIT_ON_CLOSE* ). The main() method is just a copy-paste of the original main method of the JXMapKit.

I have the following simple code to use the JXMapKit:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.DefaultTileFactory;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.GeoPosition;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.TileFactory;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.TileFactoryInfo;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyMap extends JXMapKit{
public static void main(String ... args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JXMapKit kit = new JXMapKit();
            kit.setDefaultProvider(DefaultProviders.OpenStreetMaps);


            final int max = 17;
            TileFactoryInfo info = new TileFactoryInfo(1,max-2,max,
                    256, true, true, // tile size is 256 and x/y orientation is normal
                    "http://tile.openstreetmap.org",//5/15/10.png",
                    "x","y","z") {
                public String getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
                    zoom = max-zoom;
                    String url = this.baseURL +"/"+zoom+"/"+x+"/"+y+".png";
                    return url;
                }

            };
            TileFactory tf = new DefaultTileFactory(info);
            kit.setTileFactory(tf);
            kit.setZoom(14);
            kit.setAddressLocation(new GeoPosition(22.5697, 88.3697));//coordinates of Kolkata
            kit.getMainMap().setDrawTileBorders(true);
            kit.getMainMap().setRestrictOutsidePanning(true);
            kit.getMainMap().setHorizontalWrapped(false);

            ((DefaultTileFactory)kit.getMainMap().getTileFactory()).setThreadPoolSize(8);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("JXMapKit test");
            frame.add(kit);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(500,300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solves the problem:

```
myFrame.addWindowListener(
    new WindowAdapter(){
         public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { System.exit(0); }
    }
);
```